# Warning: Parameter 1 to wp_default_styles() expected to be a reference, value given

Tags: php, wordpress

I ran this code through a debugger; it returned with no faults.

```
do {
    foreach ( (array) current($wp_filter[$tag]) as $the_ )
        if ( !is_null($the_['function']) )
            call_user_func_array($the_['function'], array_slice($args, 0, (int) $the_['accepted_args']));

} while ( next($wp_filter[$tag]) !== false );

array_pop($wp_current_filter);
```

> Warning: Parameter 1 to wp_default_styles() expected to be a reference, value given in /homepages/27/d653904259/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Jellyx/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 600

Line 600:

```
    call_user_func_array($the_['function'], array_slice($args, 0, (int) $the_['accepted_args']));
```

Comment: Code triggering the error is not even referenced

Comment: line giving error highlighted

Comment: What WP version are you using?

Comment: I use WordPress 4.6.6

Comment: Has been fixed in WP 4.7, see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/38144#comment:2

Comment: I am getting a Warning: Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in /homepages/27/d653904259/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Jellyx/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php on line 447
        $l10n[$key] = html_entity_decode( (string) $value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

Comment: Did you upgrade to WP 4.7 or higher?

Comment: I have the  latest version of WordPress

Comment: Hi See The Post (Stackoverflow)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752422/2-warning-wordpress-solved

Answer (score -4):

Update *WordPress* or try adding

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

to `wp-config.php`.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue, just avoiding it. If you care about code quality you should fix your warnings.